# Find extremum of multidimensional matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, max, minimum

I am trying to find the Extremum of a 3-dim matrix along the 2nd dimension.

I started with
`[~,index] = max(abs(mat),[],2)`, but I don't know how to advance from here. How is the index vector to be used together with the original matrix. Or is there a completely different solution to this problem?

To illustrate the task assume the following matrix:

```
mat(:,:,1) =
    23     8    -4
    -1   -26    46
mat(:,:,2) =
     5   -27    12
     2    -1    18
mat(:,:,3) =
   -10    49    39
   -13   -46    41
mat(:,:,4) =
    30   -24    18
   -40   -16   -36
```

The expected result would then be

```
ext(:,:,1) =
    23
   -46
ext(:,:,2) =
   -27
    18
ext(:,:,3) =
    49
   -46
ext(:,:,4) =
    30
   -40
```

I don't know how to use the `index` vector with `mat` to get the desired result `ext`.

Comment: I can not understand what is your question exactly. You want to find the maximum in maximum dimension and after that what?

Comment: I want to find the Maximum of absolut values along 2nd dimension multiplied by the sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate the values along dimensions 1 and 3, and then [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to combine the three indices into a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/):

```
[~, jj] = max(abs(mat),[],2); %// jj: returned by max
[ii, ~, kk] = ndgrid(1:size(mat,1),1,1:size(mat,3)); %// ii, kk: all combinations
result = mat(sub2ind(size(mat), ii, jj, kk));
```

---

A fancier, one-line alternative:

```
result = max(complex(mat),[],2);
```

This works because, acccording to [`max` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html),

> For complex input A, max returns the complex number with the largest complex modulus (magnitude), computed with max(abs(A)).

Answer (score 3):

1) If you want to find a maximum just along, let's say, 2d dimension, your variable `index` will be a matrix having dimensions (N,1,M), where N and M are number of elements of your matrix in the first and third dimensions respectively. In order to remove dummy dimensions, there is function squeeze() exist: `index=squeeze(index)` After that `size(index)` gives `N,M`

2) Depending on your problem, you probably need matlab function ind2sub(). First, you take a slice of your matrix, than find its maximum with linear indexing, and than you can restore your indicies with int2sub(). Here is an example for a 2D matrix:

```
M = randn(5,5);
[C,I] = max(M(:));
[index1,index2] = ind2sub(size(M),I);
```

Same method allows to find the absolute maximal element in whole 3D matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers my question. The right solution would yield a 2-dim array whereas treating the matrix as 1-dim as in your code returns only a scalar (or the index to it).

Comment: I have added more... Hope it is useful

Comment: I'm aware of the squeeze function. So after squeezing it, it is a NxM matrix. What do I do with it?

Comment: I guess nothing. Isn't it what you are seeking to get? Now, you know coordinates of all maximal elements in one dimension.

Comment: Each element of the matrix (N,M) is an index of maximal elements along 2d dimension in each string specified by two coordinates corresponding to the first and third dimensions.

Comment: I extended the original post (see above).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45649/discussion-between-user1618022-and-freude)